# I want to use phone number as static instead of dynamic socket id generate by socket.io lib

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat-based app (like:- WhatsApp )with socket.io. and I am want to use those person mobile number who join my app
how can I do it

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets from your chat application.

Answer (score 0):

By the docs looks like you can specify the expected id, but i think that is better to use rooms for that
When the user connected to the server just join the user to room named by the phone number

io.on("connection", (socket) => socket.join("phonenumber"))

After that you can send messages to the user by his phone number using:

io.to("phonenumber").emit("message")